# Pytest. How to add user data to the XML report?

Tags: python, xml, pytest

I want to add test data to JUnitXML if the test failed.

Trying to do it like this:

```
@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()

    for mark in item.iter_markers('datasets'):
        if report.failed:
            report.user_properties.append(('dataset', item.funcargs.get('dataset')))
```

Any attempts to verify that the test failed, only work on the "call" step. For some reason, data is written to the report only from the teardown step.

What am I doing wrong? Maybe you need to override another function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing everything right except that you are using the wrong target object to append user properties to. Append them to `item`, not to `report`:

```
@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()

    for mark in item.iter_markers('datasets'):
        if report.failed:
            item.user_properties.append(('dataset', item.funcargs.get('dataset')))
            ^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Everything worked. I fought this day!

Comment: :-) glad I could help!